# Inner join of pairs of columns of one dataframe depending on the value of one column in the other dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, inner-join

I am new in stackoverflow, not so much in R but looping is my nightmare.
I have two data.frames.

The first resembles this (100 rows with 638 variables):

```
  id   species     var_1    tl_1   var_2   tl_2   var_3   tl_3 
  1    Species_1   6250     3.4    2147    3      0.03    2
  2    Species_2   8963     7      45      2.5    754     2.2
```

The second is like this (1638018 row with 3 variables):

```
  TL   species     frac_var
  1    X1          L001
  5    X1          L001
  3    X1          L001
  1    X1          L002
  5    X1          L002
  5    X1          L002
  1    X1          L003
  2    X1          L003
  5    X1          L003
```

Now I have two perform this function

```
tot <- second_dataframe %>%
       inner_join(first_dataframe,by="species")
```

But I want that **each time the value of the column frac_var changes, R takes the value of the subsequent pair of column** (starting from the third column of this data-frame). This is needed because frac_var per each L00* will be calculated by var_*. For example, when column frac_var will be L001, I need that the inner join by species, will be done merging the first two columns (var_1, tl_1). It's equal to me if having the result in a single dataframe (which will require to include an id) or many dataframe.

Hope to have been clear enough!
Thanks a million in advance for your time.

Comment: Could you include your expected results

Answer (score 0):

Starting with some dummy data.

```
library(tidyverse)

first_dataframe <- read_table2("
 id   species     var_1    tl_1   var_2   tl_2   var_3   tl_3
  1    Species_1   6250     3.4    2147    3      0.03    2
  2    Species_2   8963     7      45      2.5    754     2.2
")

second_dataframe <- tibble(
  TL = 1:4,
  species = c("Species_1", "Species_2", "Species_1", "Species_2"),
  frac_var = c("L001", "L002", "L002", "L001")
)
```

Reshape the first data frame so that it has `frac_var`.

```
first_dataframe2 <-
  first_dataframe %>%
  pivot_longer(
    contains("_"),
    names_sep = "_",
    names_to = c("name", "frac_var")
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    frac_var = str_c("L", str_pad(frac_var, 3, pad = "0"))
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider()

first_dataframe2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>      id species   frac_var     var    tl
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 Species_1 L001     6250      3.4
#> 2     1 Species_1 L002     2147      3  
#> 3     1 Species_1 L003        0.03   2  
#> 4     2 Species_2 L001     8963      7  
#> 5     2 Species_2 L002       45      2.5
#> 6     2 Species_2 L003      754      2.2
```

Join the data frames together.

```
inner_join(first_dataframe2, second_dataframe)
#> Joining, by = c("species", "frac_var")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>      id species   frac_var   var    tl    TL
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1 Species_1 L001      6250   3.4     1
#> 2     1 Species_1 L002      2147   3       3
#> 3     2 Species_2 L001      8963   7       4
#> 4     2 Species_2 L002        45   2.5     2
```

Comment: Paul thanks! It worked as you showed but the frac_var is a fraction of the var which value should be taken per each row per each L00*. When I calculate the inner_join on singular dataframe the column frac_var gets filled by fractions of the data 6250 for the first row for example. It is pretty hide inside the function inner join this, that's why I am not able to explain it better. Hope you can help me with this as well. Thanks a million for you time!

Comment: Can you add the expected output to the question?

Comment: 'tl      species      frac_var          var_1     tl_1'                                              
              '2.0'    Alos       0.000075           0.85        3'                                     
              '2.1'    Alos       0.00033           0.85        3'                                    
              '2.2     Alos       0.045                 0.85        3'                                   
              '2.3     Alos       0.0095               0.85        3'

Comment: Sorry, I could not write it any better. Frac_var is a fraction of var_1 and I have obtained it from the starting dataframe of the "second dataframe" of my initial example doing : a <- my_csv %>%
  tidyr::gather(species, frac_var, -tl)